# Stein's extension operator for fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

In his book Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions,
Stein constructs an extension operator $\mathcal{E}:W^{m,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow
W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\le p<\infty$, in domains of the form
$$
\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}\times\mathbb{R}:\,y>f(x)\},
$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}^{N-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz continuous
function. Let $\phi:[1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function
be such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\phi(t)\,dt=1,\quad\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{n}\phi(t)\,dt=0,\quad
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}t^{n}\phi(t)=0\label{sIII s5}%
\end{equation}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Given $u\in W^{m,p}(\Omega)$, the extension
$\mathcal{E}(u)$ to $\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\overline{\Omega}$ is given by by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}(u)(x,y):=%
%TCIMACRO{\dint _{1}^{\infty}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}}
%EndExpansion
\phi(t)u(x,y+3t\sqrt{1+L^{2}}d_{\operatorname*{reg}}(x,y))\,dt,\label{sIII s6}%
\end{equation}
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$ and $d_{\operatorname*{reg}}$ is
the regularized distance to $\partial\Omega$.

Since the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$, $0<s<1$, is obtained by
interpolating $L^{p}(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and since $\mathcal{E}%
:L^{p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ and $\mathcal{E}%
:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ are continuous, one can
use interpolation theory to show that $\mathcal{E}:W^{s,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow
W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ is a continuous extension operator.

I was trying to give a direct proof of this fact by using the explicit
seminorm
$$
v\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\Omega}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}%
\setminus\Omega}\frac{|v(X)-v(Y)|^{p}}{|X-Y|^{N+sp}}dXdY,
$$
where $X=(x,y)$. I tried adding and subtracting stuff but I would need a
change of variables to get back to $\Omega$